# C++ vectors: emplace_back vs. push_back

Tags: c++11, vector, back, emplace

Why  is the method emplace_back() necessary at all?

Why can compiler constructors not simply use the faster "create at end" way, when implementing push_back()?
What part of the C++ standard prohibits that?
What would be the problem in adjusting this part of the standard instead of introducing still another method? As far as I can see, the anonymous object constructed, copied, then deleted has no further life or purpose afterwards.

What is the merit of having two completely equivalent methods, one faster, the other more commonly known and used? Or IS there a difference?

Comment: What anonymous object? The parameter of `push_back` is not anonymous. It is very much a named variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation, copying and destruction of the temporary object may have side effects, so the compiler is not allowed to generally skip them even if it is aware that the call to `push_back` does not cause any other use of the temporary object. This way `push_back` with a temporary as argument may behave differently than the equivalent `emplace_back` directly from the constructor arguments. If the compiler realizes that there are no side effects, it can of course optimize a `push_back` call to the same machine code it would emit for an equivalent `emplace_back` call.

Also, `push_back` allows for list initialization of the temporary object in its argument, while `emplace_back` always uses (non-list) direct initialization. So some uses of `push_back` with a temporary are not valid for `emplace_back`.

Furthermore, `push_back` has been there since the beginning of standardized C++ and earlier, but variadic templates exists only since C++11. So it wouldn't have been possible to specify `emplace_back` before C++11. It would have needed to be limited to some arbitrary finite number of arguments. Also without C++11 forwarding references it doesn't work out so nicely either.

If you don't need to support anything before C++11 then you can almost always use `emplace_back` and ignore `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare them, using the reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

`push_back` takes a reference or rvalue reference.

`emplace_back` takes a parameter pack. `emplace_back` is used to construct a type "in place", whereas `push_back` can only move or copy an object, not construct it in place.

(Note that `push_back` can implicitly call a constructor function, but this causes two function calls. A constructor function call followed by a move or copy. That is not the same for `emplace_back` which calls a constructor only.)

For example, consider a non-trivial type:

```
struct ContainsAFewThings
{
    ContainsAFewThings(a, b)
        : a(a)
        , b(b)
    {
    }

    int a;
    int b;
}
```

We can construct it directly using `emplace_back`.

```
std::vector<ContainsAFewThings> vect;
vect.emplace_back(1, 2);
```

This performs one call to the constructor function, and no calls to a move or copy constructor. The alternative with `push_back` calls the constructor function, then copy or move:

```
std::vector<ContainsAFewThings> vect;
vect.push_back(ContainsAFewThings(1, 2)); // push_back with explicit constructor

// does the same thing as this:
vect.push_back(1, 2); // hidden impicit constructor call here!
```

To understand more, learn about perfect forwarding and "The Forwarding Problem" in C++. There is a discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-stdforward-and-which-problems-does-it-solve).